# Will HTTP Compression (GZip or deflate) on a low traffic site actually be beneficial?

Tags: http, compression, gzip

I have a web application where the client will be running off a local server (i.e. - requests will not be going out over the net).  The site will be quite low traffic and so I am trying to figure out if the actual de-compression is expensive in this type of a system.  Performance is an issue so I will have caching set up, but I was considering compression as well.  I will not have bandwidth issues as the site is very low traffic.  So, I am just trying to figure out if compression will do more harm than good in this type of system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [good article](http://henry.precheur.org/2009/4/23/GZIP_encoding_%3D_happier_users%3F.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

On pretty much any modern system with a solid web stack, compression will not be expensive, but it seems to me that you won't be gaining any positive effects from it whatsoever, no matter how minor the overhead.  I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 1):

When you measured the performance, how did the numbers compare? Was it faster when you had compression enabled, or not?

Comment: I havent done it yet.  I was trying to see if it is even worth it.  May be a good option to profile each...thx.

Answer (score 1):

I have used compression but users were running over a wireless 3G network at various remote locations.  Compression made a significant different to the bandwidth usage in this case.

For users running locally, and with bandwidth not an issue, I don't think it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

For cachable resources (.js, .html, .css) files, I think it doesn't make sense after the browser caches these resources.

But for non-cachable resources (e.g. json response) I think it makes sense.